# Ansible ec2_win_password module fails on Windows 2022, but works on Windows 2019

Tags: windows, ansible, ansible-awx

Using the identical Ansible code that works fine on Windows 2019, I encounter a fatal error on Windows 2022.  Here is the code:

```
name: Grab the windows password we need from AWS to write to inventory
  ec2_win_password:
    aws_access_key: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.secret_key }}"
    security_token: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.session_token }}"
    instance_id: "{{ created_instance.instance_ids.0 }}"
    key_file: "{{ secret_key }}"
    region: "{{ target_region }}"
    wait: yes
  register: win_password
```

Here is the error I see:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "access_key": "A.....",
            "aws_access_key": "A.....",
            "aws_ca_bundle": null,
            "aws_config": null,
            "aws_secret_key": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "debug_botocore_endpoint_logs": false,
            "endpoint_url": null,
            "instance_id": "i-0123456789",
            "key_data": null,
            "key_file": "/runner/env/tmpeol1opcf",
            "key_passphrase": null,
            "profile": null,
            "region": "us-east-1",
            "secret_key": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "security_token": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "session_token": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "validate_certs": true,
            "wait": true,
            "wait_timeout": 120
        }
    },
    "msg": "wait for password timeout after 120 seconds"
}
```

Is the ec2_win_password Ansible module incompatible with Windows 2022?

Comment: Well, does [`aws ec2 get-password-data`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/get-password-data.html) retrieve it but ansible does not? Did you heed the warning on that page about waiting 15 minutes before attempting to ask for the password?

Comment: Yes, I did wait 15 minutes.  It works fine with a Windows 2016 and Windows 2019 instance, but fails with Windows 2022.

Comment: "it" what works? The awscli version or ansible? What I'm asking is whether this is strictly an ansible module bug, or there's some other star out of alignment. If the awscli version works but ansible does not, then we have more information to go on

Comment: The `aws ec2 get-password-data` command gives a result for the PasswordData for Windows 2016 and 2019.  However, for Windows 2022 the same AWS CLI command never returns a value for PasswordData.

Comment: Then there's your answer; ansible modules are merely automation around existing apis so if aws's own tooling can't do it, neither can ansible. This has now moved into the realm of a system administration problem and thus belongs on serverfault or maybe devops.stackexchange.com. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been identified.  AWS Windows 2022 EC2(AMI) is using EC2Launch V2 by default, but Windows 2016/2019 uses EC2Launch (V1).  These references describe what I was experiencing:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2launch-v2.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2launch.html

If deploying the Windows 2022 EC2 via code, which I was, then these two PowerShell scripts need to be run:

`C:/Program Files/Amazon/EC2Launch/ec2launch' reset --block`

`C:/Program Files/Amazon/EC2Launch/ec2launch' sysprep --shutdown --block`

Here is an example of how to do so using Packer:

https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/packer-with-aws-ec2launch/15244